# Duplicate Symbols when Mixing C and C++

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker-errors, sdl-2

I'm trying to learn how to use the [SDL2 KISS](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl) project/toolkit/library-thing, via the [example provided in the manual](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl/blob/master/kiss_manual.pdf) (found on page 4). Whenever I link it, however, it fails, citing duplicate symbol errors. The two *[example files](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl/blob/master/kiss_example1.c)* provided in the repo build, compile, and work fine.

My hypothesis is that because I'm trying to write the example code from the manual into a C++ file, and the library is pure C89, there is some angry internal compiler explosion going on. If I forward declare a C function with the same code, everything seems to be okay, but I'd really like to not have a bunch of C++ files that exist purely as delegates to call C functions.

It does say in the project [readme](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl/blob/master/README.md) (at the end of the first paragraph) that everything is C++ compatible, and is actually written in the same way that the SDL2 library is written- which I can use without issue. The SDL2 KISS header seems to be correctly setup for use with C++, using:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

As far as possible causes for the `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` linker errors go, I have three suspects: my ignorance about mixing pure C with C++, the CMakeLists I wrote for the project, or an issue in the library itself (which I think is incredibly unlikely). I've been messing with different potential solutions for a few days, but haven't come across anything better than forward declaring (which, again, I don't want to do). Bellow you'll find the exact errors, my `main.cpp` file, which contains exclusively the code from the manual, and the `CMakeLists` file I wrote. The code posted does *not* build for me, but I can post the working C++ file which forward declares a C function, if that would be helpful.

#### Make error from terminal

```
Scanning dependencies of target Test_KISS
[ 16%] Linking CXX executable bin/Test_KISS
duplicate symbol _kiss_border in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_green in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_progress_interval in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_click_interval in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_black in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_slider_padding in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_spacing in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_textfont_size in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_buttonfont_size in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_lightblue in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_blue in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_white in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
duplicate symbol _kiss_edge in:
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/include/kiss_draw.c.o
ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/Test_KISS] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test_KISS.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "kiss_sdl.h"


void button_event(kiss_button *button, SDL_Event *e, int *draw, int *quit)
{
    if (kiss_button_event (button, e, draw))
        *quit = 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Event e;

    kiss_array objects;
    kiss_window window;
    kiss_label label;
    kiss_button button;

    char message[KISS_MAX_LENGTH];
    int draw = 1;
    int quit = 0;

    kiss_array_new (&objects);
    renderer = kiss_init ("Test KISS SDL", &objects, 320, 120);
    kiss_window_new (&window, NULL, 0, 0, 0, kiss_screen_width, kiss_screen_height);
    strcpy (message, "Hello, world!");

    kiss_label_new (&label, &window, message, window.rect.w / 2 - strlen (message) * kiss_textfont.advance / 2, window.rect.h / 2 - (kiss_textfont.fontheight + 2 * kiss_normal.h) / 2);
    label.textcolor.r = 255;

    kiss_button_new (&button, &window, "Okay", window.rect.w / 2 - kiss_normal.w / 2, label.rect.y + kiss_textfont.fontheight + kiss_normal.h);
    window.visible = 1;

    while (!quit)
    {

        SDL_Delay (10);
        while (SDL_PollEvent (&e))
        {

             if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                 quit = 1;

             kiss_window_event (&window, &e, &draw);
             button_event (&button, &e, &draw, &quit);
        }

        if (!draw)
            continue;

        SDL_RenderClear (renderer);
        kiss_window_draw (&window, renderer);
        kiss_label_draw (&label, renderer);
        kiss_button_draw (&button, renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent (renderer);
        draw = 0;
    }

    kiss_clean (&objects);
    return 0;
}
```

#### CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Test_KISS)


set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${Test_KISS_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(BIN_DIR ${Test_KISS_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)


#Define Preprocessor Macros (RESDIR found in include/kiss_sdl.h)
add_definitions(-DRESDIR=\"../../resources/\")


find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories(include)


add_executable(Test_KISS src/main.cpp include/kiss_draw.c include/kiss_general.c include/kiss_posix.c include/kiss_widgets.c)


target_link_libraries(Test_KISS ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS Test_KISS RUNTIME DESTINATION ${BIN_DIR})
```

If I can provide any more information to help, please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[kiss_sdl.h](https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl/blob/master/kiss_sdl.h) actually *defines* numerous variables:

```
double kiss_spacing;
int kiss_textfont_size, kiss_buttonfont_size;
int kiss_click_interval, kiss_progress_interval;
int kiss_slider_padding;
int kiss_border, kiss_edge;
int kiss_screen_width, kiss_screen_height;
```

Those variables get defined in every C/C++ file that `#include`'s the file.  Thus you get duplicate symbols - because there **are** duplicate symbols.

The fix?  Fix the code so that it properly [declares the variables instead of defining them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).

In other words, the code is broken.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll look into this more, but should I report back to the library's creator, or is this something I've done wrong? Also, what code should be fixed, the header, or a different file?

Comment: @MichaelBethke - A header file meant for inclusion into multiple files that use a library should not *define* variables like that.  Without digging into the library code and its documentation, I can't really say *how* best to fix it - and that would only be my opinion anyway.  If you're using it as the documentation says to, the only way you'll get it to work is to either use a link-time option to accept duplicate symbols, or change your code in such a way that you include that header file in just one of your source files.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input! I'll contact the library creator to see what they say about reviewing the header's definitions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now. extern "C" though means that the declarations under it are like C++, and the rest of the code is compiled like C, like mine is C89. If compiled with a C compiler, and files with c extension. Rightly understanding this is what fixed the problem.

Simple universal GUI widget toolkit for SDL2 https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl , written by me.